# does the matlab R2017a deploy neural network for c#(.net Assemly)

Tags: c#, matlab

I use matlab R2017a but when i want to deploy my code to c#(.net assembly) it has a lot of error my code is very simple but i dont know why the matlab dont compile it in c#(.net assembly)

Below snapshots of error in compiling neural network.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

does the c# visual studio run my code with this errors because the matlab created files specially dll file(does this dll file work in the visual studio?) this is my simple code of neural network

```
function neuralnetwork(x,t)

net= fitnet(10);

disp('Training fitnet');

train(net,x,t);

end
```

does this version just have this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you type *ver* in command window, in R2017a we have Fixed-Point Designer but not the Simulink Fixed Point toolbox. As it is shown in the error picture it has warnings related to Fixed-Point Designer toolbox even if you don't use that functions. You can ignore these warnings or run your code in R2017b. By the way, your question is answered [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/374776-does-the-matlab-r2017a-deploy-neural-network-for-c-net-assemly).

Comment: does the matlab r2017b fix this issue?

Comment: @wahed fazeli, you can even do that in Matlab r2017a, just you should add 2 dll files . For complete answer, please see [This Page](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/374776-does-the-matlab-r2017a-deploy-neural-network-for-c-net-assemly?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com)

Comment: The answer in [This Page](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/374776-does-the-matlab-r2017a-deploy-neural-network-for-c-net-assemly?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) was updated and solved your problem in r2017a.